# Youtube API v3 exporting videos

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i create a program that take in input some information and search for the first 10 video on youtube, my problem is that the v2 version of Youtube API isn't support, so i change that

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=
```

with new version,but i dont find that. Can you help me please?
Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

Thanks a lot , i have tried to do this command

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=skyrim&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

i want search the first 10 video related to the keyword Skyrim.
I try this using eclipse and i have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP errorfetching URL. Status=400, URL=https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&q=skyrim&max-results=10
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:590)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
```

I run the query in this mode :

```
private static String QueryURL ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&q=";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(QueryURL+stringa).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36").get();
```

Where stringa is = Skyrim.
Thanks all for help

Comment: Refer : [Youtube-api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java)

Answer (score 0):

Start at the YouTube API v3 page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/